# phpExcel: error in getCalculatedValue()

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have an error reading a excel 2007 spreadsheet, when I try to get the calculated value from a Cell. This is how the code looks like (I've made a simple test code, just to try diferent things):

```
$reader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$reader->setReadDataOnly(false);
$reader->setLoadSheetsOnly('Operació');

$excel     = $reader->load('../Data/Coordinacio EXS.XLSX');
$worksheet = $excel->getSheet(0);

echo 'lets see ' . $worksheet->getCell('A2')->getValue() . '<br>';
echo 'formula ' . $worksheet->getCell('AW2')->getValue() . '<br>';
echo 'getCalculatedValue ' . $worksheet->getCell('AW2')->getCalculatedValue();
echo '<br><br>';

echo 'lets see ' . $worksheet->getCell('A3')->getValue() . '<br>';
echo 'formula ' . $worksheet->getCell('AW3')->getValue() . '<br>';
echo 'getCalculatedValue ' . $worksheet->getCell('AW3')->getCalculatedValue();
echo '<br><br>';

echo 'lets see ' . $worksheet->getCell('A4')->getValue() . '<br>';
echo 'formula ' . $worksheet->getCell('AW4')->getValue() . '<br>';
echo 'getCalculatedValue ' . $worksheet->getCell('AW4')->getCalculatedValue();
echo '<br><br>';
```

Nothing special, as you see. When I run this code, I've got this exception:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception' with message 'Operació!AW4 -> Formula Error: An unexpected error occured' in C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\vendors\PHPOffice\PHPExcel\1.8.1\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php on line 293 PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception: Operació!AW4 -> Formula Error: An unexpected error occured in C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\vendors\PHPOffice\PHPExcel\1.8.1\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php on line 293 Call Stack: 0.0015 358240 1. {main}() C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\carrega-excepcions\app\provar.php:0 31.3571 152068448 2. PHPExcel_Cell->getCalculatedValue() C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\carrega-excepcions\app\provar.php:56
```

If I look into the Excel itself, the formula is:

```
=SI([@[Codi Diàleg]]="";[@[Dept Aux]];BUSCARV([@[Codi Diàleg]];'CMI - Llistats mestres'!$I$2:$Q$4000;2;FALSO))
```

When PHPExcel reads this formula and I do a echo of this:

```
=IF(Tabla3[[#This Row],[Codi Diàleg]]="",Tabla3[[#This Row],[Dept Aux]],VLOOKUP(Tabla3[[#This Row],[Codi Diàleg]],'CMI - Llistats mestres'!$I$2:$Q$4000,2,FALSE))
```

To make a test, I have change a little bit the formula. The idea is to use of cells ranges, instead of named ranges. Just like that:

```
=SI(AP2="";AO2;BUSCARV(AP2;Hoja5!$I$2:$Q$4000;2;FALSO))
```

This formula, when is readed by PHPExcel, it turns into:

```
=IF(AP2="",AO2,VLOOKUP(AP2,[2]Hoja5!$I$2:$Q$4000,2,FALSE))
```

And now the getCalculatedValue() method works as espected. So, seems PHPExcel's Calculation Engine do not work well with named ranges, even with named cells (like "Codi Diàleg").

I do not want to ask to end user to change the formula, I would prefer to find a solution with PHPExcel. Seem's the way is to use getOldCalculatedValue() instead of getCalculatedValue(), but I'm not sure if this value is always available / confiable.

¿Any suggestions to solve this?.

Thank's,

Ferran.